# Filter list using lambda or anything easier

Tags: c#, lambda

```
var id = new List<int> {2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 3, 5};

var memberOrders = _orderRepository.GetMemberOrders(memberId).ToList();
```

Now i want to filter list 2 using list 1 id's without foreach or for loops.Please Help me.

Comment: What field would you be filtering on? OrderId? If you show the `foreach` way you are doing it, we can help convert it to Linq.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Enumerable.Intersect extension Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb460136(v=vs.100).aspx) method as below:

MSDN :

> Produces the set intersection of two sequences by using the default
>   equality comparer to compare values.

```
        var id1 = new List<int> { 2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 3, 5 };
        var id2 = new List<int> { 2, 9, 7, 3, 15};
        var memberOrders = id1.Intersect(id2);
```

**Output: 2,9,3**

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the method `GetMemberOrders` returns all orders for the specified `memberId`. If you want to filter those orders on the `id` list, you can use the `List.Contains()` method to only return orders that have a match.

If this assumption is correct, you could help reduce confusion by using more meaningful names, for example:

```
var orderIdFilter = new List<int> {2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 3, 5};

var filteredMemberOrders = _orderRepository.GetMemberOrders(memberId)
    .Where(order => orderIdFilter.Contains(order.Id))
    .ToList();
```